# How to translate this code to VB.net (creating a huge dictionary object)?

Tags: php, vb.net

```
$whoisservers = array(
    "ac" =>"whois.nic.ac",
    "ae" =>"whois.nic.ae",
    "aero"=>"whois.aero",
    "af" =>"whois.nic.af",
    "ag" =>"whois.nic.ag",
    "al" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "am" =>"whois.amnic.net",
    "arpa" =>"whois.iana.org",
    "as" =>"whois.nic.as",
    "asia" =>"whois.nic.asia",
    "at" =>"whois.nic.at",
    "au" =>"whois.aunic.net",
    "az" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "ba" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "be" =>"whois.dns.be",
    "bg" =>"whois.register.bg",
    "bi" =>"whois.nic.bi",
    "biz" =>"whois.biz",
    "bj" =>"whois.nic.bj",
    "br" =>"whois.registro.br",
    "bt" =>"whois.netnames.net",
    "by" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "bz" =>"whois.belizenic.bz",
    "ca" =>"whois.cira.ca",
    "cat" =>"whois.cat",
    "cc" =>"whois.nic.cc",
    "cd" =>"whois.nic.cd",
    "ch" =>"whois.nic.ch",
    "ci" =>"whois.nic.ci",
    "ck" =>"whois.nic.ck",
    "cl" =>"whois.nic.cl",
    "cn" =>"whois.cnnic.net.cn",
    "com" =>"whois.verisign-grs.com",
    "coop" =>"whois.nic.coop",
    "cx" =>"whois.nic.cx",
    "cy" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "cz" =>"whois.nic.cz",
    "de" =>"whois.denic.de",
    "dk" =>"whois.dk-hostmaster.dk",
    "dm" =>"whois.nic.cx",
    "dz" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "edu" =>"whois.educause.edu",
    "ee" =>"whois.eenet.ee",
    "eg" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "es" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "eu" =>"whois.eu",
    "fi" =>"whois.ficora.fi",
    "fo" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "fr" =>"whois.nic.fr",
    "gb" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "gd" =>"whois.adamsnames.com",
    "ge" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "gg" =>"whois.channelisles.net",
    "gi" =>"whois2.afilias-grs.net",
    "gl" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "gm" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "gov" =>"whois.nic.gov",
    "gr" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "gs" =>"whois.nic.gs",
    "gw" =>"whois.nic.gw",
    "gy" =>"whois.registry.gy",
    "hk" =>"whois.hkirc.hk",
    "hm" =>"whois.registry.hm",
    "hn" =>"whois2.afilias-grs.net",
    "hr" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "hu" =>"whois.nic.hu",
    "ie" =>"whois.domainregistry.ie",
    "il" =>"whois.isoc.org.il",
    "in" =>"whois.inregistry.net",
    "info" =>"whois.afilias.net",
    "int" =>"whois.iana.org",
    "io" =>"whois.nic.io",
    "iq" =>"vrx.net",
    "ir" =>"whois.nic.ir",
    "is" =>"whois.isnic.is",
    "it" =>"whois.nic.it",
    "je" =>"whois.channelisles.net",
    "jobs" =>"jobswhois.verisign-grs.com",
    "jp" =>"whois.jprs.jp",
    "ke" =>"whois.kenic.or.ke",
    "kg" =>"www.domain.kg",
    "ki" =>"whois.nic.ki",
    "kr" =>"whois.nic.or.kr",
    "kz" =>"whois.nic.kz",
    "la" =>"whois.nic.la",
    "li" =>"whois.nic.li",
    "lt" =>"whois.domreg.lt",
    "lu" =>"whois.dns.lu",
    "lv" =>"whois.nic.lv",
    "ly" =>"whois.nic.ly",
    "ma" =>"whois.iam.net.ma",
    "mc" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "md" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "me" =>"whois.meregistry.net",
    "mg" =>"whois.nic.mg",
    "mil" =>"whois.nic.mil",
    "mn" =>"whois.nic.mn",
    "mobi" =>"whois.dotmobiregistry.net",
    "ms" =>"whois.adamsnames.tc",
    "mt" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "mu" =>"whois.nic.mu",
    "museum" =>"whois.museum",
    "mx" =>"whois.nic.mx",
    "my" =>"whois.mynic.net.my",
    "na" =>"whois.na-nic.com.na",
    "name" =>"whois.nic.name",
    "net" =>"whois.verisign-grs.net",
    "nf" =>"whois.nic.nf",
    "nl" =>"whois.domain-registry.nl",
    "no" =>"whois.norid.no",
    "nu" =>"whois.nic.nu",
    "nz" =>"whois.srs.net.nz",
    "org" =>"whois.pir.org",
    "pl" =>"whois.dns.pl",
    "pm" =>"whois.nic.pm",
    "pr" =>"whois.uprr.pr",
    "pro" =>"whois.registrypro.pro",
    "pt" =>"whois.dns.pt",
    "re" =>"whois.nic.re",
    "ro" =>"whois.rotld.ro",
    "ru" =>"whois.ripn.net",
    "sa" =>"whois.nic.net.sa",
    "sb" =>"whois.nic.net.sb",
    "sc" =>"whois2.afilias-grs.net",
    "se" =>"whois.iis.se",
    "sg" =>"whois.nic.net.sg",
    "sh" =>"whois.nic.sh",
    "si" =>"whois.arnes.si",
    "sk" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "sm" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "st" =>"whois.nic.st",
    "su" =>"whois.ripn.net",
    "tc" =>"whois.adamsnames.tc",
    "tel" =>"whois.nic.tel",
    "tf" =>"whois.nic.tf",
    "th" =>"whois.thnic.net",
    "tj" =>"whois.nic.tj",
    "tk" =>"whois.dot.tk",
    "tl" =>"whois.nic.tl",
    "tm" =>"whois.nic.tm",
    "tn" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "to" =>"whois.tonic.to",
    "tp" =>"whois.nic.tl",
    "tr" =>"whois.nic.tr",
    "travel" =>"whois.nic.travel",
    "tv" => "tvwhois.verisign-grs.com",
    "tw" =>"whois.twnic.net.tw",
    "ua" =>"whois.net.ua",
    "ug" =>"whois.co.ug",
    "uk" =>"whois.nic.uk",
    "us" =>"whois.nic.us",
    "uy" =>"nic.uy",
    "uz" =>"whois.cctld.uz",
    "va" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "vc" =>"whois2.afilias-grs.net",
    "ve" =>"whois.nic.ve",
    "vg" =>"whois.adamsnames.tc",
    "wf" =>"whois.nic.wf",
    "ws" =>"whois.website.ws",
    "yt" =>"whois.nic.yt",
    "yu" =>"whois.ripe.net");
```

I know how to create dictionary of string. I just need an elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB.Net (starting from VS2010) you can use `From` to init a dictionary.

```
    Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
        {
            {"KeyA", "ValueA"},
            {"KeyB", "ValueB"},
            {"KeyC", "ValueC"}
        }
```